# C: updating memory address contents using pointers with ++ / --

Tags: c, pointers, memory, updating

I was wondering, why does:

```
*some_var++;
```

not do the same as:

```
*some_var = *some_var + 1;
```

... is it because in the second example the <*> dereferencing operator is being used for two distinct purposes?

```
*some_var = *some_var + 1;
```

Which is to say: the first instance of ***some_var** is setting the contents of **&some_var** whereas the second instance of ***some_var** is calling the current contents of **&some_var**? ...That being a distinction C cannot make with the statement: ***some_var++;**?

Furthermore, does:

```
*some_var++;
```

do anything, and if so, what?!

Thanks for any input... perhaps a trivial matter but I am curious nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks, my pre-question search didn't uncover that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
*some_var++;
```

is equivalent to

```
*(some_var++);
```

and not equivalent to:

```
(*some_var)++;
```

`++` postfix operator has higher precedence than `*` unary operator.

By the way, as you don't use the value of the `*` operator in your statement, `*some_var++;` statement is also equivalent to `some_var++;` (assuming `some_var` is not a pointer to a `volatile` object).

Comment: +1 When you don't care to remember the order of precedence of operators, use parenthesis. The non-experts who follow you will appreciate it. In some cases, GCC will even suggest it.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I generally agree to this, but `*ptr++` is a form that any decent C programmer should be able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

see the following examples:

```
ex: 1

int main()
{
  char *ptr = "stackoverflow";
  *ptr++;
  printf ("%s\n", ptr);//this will print "tackoverflow" i.e pointr is incremented.
  return 0;
}

ex:2

int main()
{
   char *ptr = "stackoverflow";
   *ptr = *ptr + 1;// here you are trying to assing incremented content to *ptr, but this will give you error because string literal "stackoverflow" is stored in the read only memory so you can't modify .
}
```